# Upload a wav file to server in Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to upload `wav` files to a server in c# in unity3d.

I made already a upload system with `png` files but for some reason it doesn't work with `wav` files

Here is the image upload script I changed it so it will work with audio but it doesn't work the error I still get is from the php file which says failed

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;


public class Upload : MonoBehaviour
{



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 0, 500, 20), Application.dataPath);
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 100, 150, 20), "Upload"))
    {
        UploadFile("http://localhost:8888/unity/upload.php");
    }
}

IEnumerator UploadFileCo(string uploadURL)
{
    WWW localFile = new WWW("file:///1.wav");
    yield return localFile;
    WWWForm postForm = new WWWForm();
    postForm.AddBinaryData("file", localFile.bytes, "1.wav");
    WWW upload = new WWW(uploadURL, postForm);
    yield return upload;
    if (upload.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log(upload.text);
        Debug.Log ("upload error null");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error during upload: " + upload.error);
    }
}

void UploadFile(string uploadURL)
{
    StartCoroutine(UploadFileCo(uploadURL));
}

}
```

Here is the php script

```
<?php
$thefile = $_FILES['file'];

 if(!empty($theFile))
 {
 echo "Success!";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Failed!";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I get a failed error from the server

Comment: i can not run the code it gives me this error Assets/Upload.cs(37,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.WWW' to `bool'

Comment: It stull puts out good

Comment: i get Bytes 53599216

Comment: i have my self mamp to test on it thanks for your help so far :P

Comment: Hi i found the problem it was something with the audio file not the script thank you again for your help :D